# Illegal SEGMENT fixup index in module from Embarcadero c++ linker

Tags: c++, linker

I am getting the following link error.  "[ilink32 Error] Fatal: Illegal SEGMENT fixup index in module". Looking through the online help I have found that this problem was fixed in version 10.4.  I am running Borland C++ Builder on a windows 10 machine.  The only help I found online says that the module is probably corrupt.  But when I rebuild the module and relink I get the same error.  My project is dead in the water at this point.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when I link a lib that calls the insert function for an std::vector, std::unordered_set etc. If I comment it out in the lib the error disappears. I built by myself the lib (an opensource proj) both whit the C++Builder 10.4 and 11 as well.

Comment: How does this answer the question?